# What is catalog_product_link_attribute_int used for in Magento v1.9?

Tags: database

The table catalog_product_link_attribute_int is huge in a couple of stores I have built.

A store with 1600 products has this table at 771MiB in which is over 10x the size of the next largest table. It makes the store awkward to backup or migrate and it can't be normal. On other sites it's usually around 50kb but on at least one other site it is over 700Mib.

Is this table safe to truncate? What does it actually do?

Answer (score 2):

`catalog_product_link` is the table that holds the data when you create related products, upsells, etc.

The `link_id` of that table links to the `catalog_product_link_attribute_int`.

The `product_link_attribute_id` of that table links to the `catalog_product_link_attribute` table.

The `link_type_id` of that table links to the `catalog_product_link_type` table.

In English, `catalog_product_link_attribute_int` holds some integer type information about a `catalog_product_link` row. For example, the position it has, so Magento knows what order to position the related products when displaying them.